# Purpose of measure $\mu \equiv 0$

Tags: measure-theory

Purpose of measure $\mu \equiv 0$. I just stumbled on the exclusion of this case in a proof and thought it was a funny measure. Does this measure have any purpose in anything?

Comment: Yes. It is useful for asking questions about. (And horrible grammar with  badly used prepositions.)

Comment: I don't see any prepositions :p But yes, point taken.

Comment: It was a comment on my own grammar :-).

Comment: Haha, but all right then ;)

Comment: As an aside, 'extreme' cases such as $\mu=0$ are often a good test of understanding.

Comment: Indeed, I had to go back and check every proof so far since I hadn't even thought of it.

Comment: @copper.hat  Ending sentences with prepositions has _never_ been improper.  It's strictly meme among poorly educated elementary school marms.  Ditto with split infinitives.

Comment: @B.Goddard: You mean all of my beatings were for nothing?

Comment: @copper.hat Only if you think "building character" is nothing;-)

Comment: @B.Goddard: Still hate the taste of carbolic soap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set of finite signed measures on a $\sigma$-algebra is a vector space with respect to the usual operations. That vector space needs an identity element.